# ComboBox, suggesting text

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

In my application, I have a ComboBox that consist of all of the fonts installed in System. I want to add the functionality, that after the user write a letter, it behaves like this:

[image]

This means **I don't want to use AutoCompleteMode and AutoCompleteSource properties**.

Here is my code handling TextUpdate event for CB:

```
private void tsComboBoxFontChoice_TextUpdate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.isBackClicked)
    {
        int caretPosition = this.tsComboBoxFontChoice.Text.Length;
        bool isFound = false;
        StringBuilder sbComboBox = new StringBuilder(this.tsComboBoxFontChoice.Text);
        StringBuilder sbTextToAppend = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < this.systemFonts.Families.Length;i++ )
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(this.systemFonts.Families[i].Name);
            sbTextToAppend = new StringBuilder(this.systemFonts.Families[i].Name);
            int tempStopIndex= sbComboBox.Length;

            if (tempStopIndex <= sb.Length)
            {
                sb.Remove(tempStopIndex,
                this.systemFonts.Families[i].Name.Length - tempStopIndex).ToString(); //A
            }

            if(sbComboBox.ToString() == sb.ToString())
            {
                sbTextToAppend.Remove(0, tempStopIndex).ToString();   //rial
                isFound = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (isFound)
        {
            sbComboBox.Append(sbTextToAppend);
            this.tsComboBoxFontChoice.Text = sbComboBox.ToString();
            this.tsComboBoxFontChoice.Select(caretPosition, sbComboBox.Length);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        this.isBackClicked = false;
    }
}
```

This code works perfectly, **but it is really slow**. As you can see, I've tried to use StringBuilder, so that I could avoid copying context of the string while concatenation and removing parts of it.

Can you tell me how can I improve my code? Do I need completely different approach or maybe there's something I could do better here?

Thanks!

Comment: What is `systemFonts`? You can simply use `systemFonts.FirstOrDefault(o => o.StartWith(comboBox.Text))` to find first match (or `null` if no match).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's *decompose* your solution (*extract a method*):

```
 // we (as a suggested font name) such a name of a system font that
 //  - starts with the prefix
 //  - if there're many such names 
 //    (e.g. "Arial", "Arial narrow" for "Ar") take the shortest
 //  - when there're no fonts found just return prefix 
 private static String suggestedFontName(String prefix) {
   String result = System.Drawing.FontFamily.Families
     .Select(font => font.Name)
     .Where(name => name.StartsWith(prefix, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
     .OrderBy(name => name.Length)
     .ThenBy(name => name)
     .FirstOrDefault();

   return String.IsNullOrEmpty(result) ? prefix : result;
}
```

And so

```
private void tsComboBoxFontChoice_TextUpdate(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  ComboBox box = sender as ComboBox;

  // To prevent calling the event when we're adding tips for user
  box.TextUpdate -= tsComboBoxFontChoice_TextUpdate;

  try {
    String oldText = box.Text;
    String suggested = suggestedFontName(oldText);

    box.Text = suggested;
    box.Select(oldText.Length, suggested.Length - oldText.Length);
  }
  finally {
    // the text is updated, so let's continue listening TextUpdate event
    box.TextUpdate += tsComboBoxFontChoice_TextUpdate;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this great answer! It made me learn about lambda expressions, I've never used that before and it's really powerful.

Answer (score 1):

You could compare what has been typed before creating the `StringBuilder`s:

```
string typed = this.tsComboBoxFontChoice.Text;
for (int i = 0; i < this.systemFonts.Families.Length; i++)
{
    string candidate = this.systemFonts.Families[i].Name;
    if (!candidate.StartsWith(typed))
    {
        continue;
    }

    // it's a match! 
    ...
}
```

This way you don't end up computing the "text to append" for fonts that don't even match the current value.

I doubt you need to use `StringBuilder`s at all, by the way.